# Why Is the sectionId for the Rows in My Table Undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**EDIT:** It seems there was an issue with the way I was using `sectionId` within the `eventListener`. Previously the event listener was capturing the value of `sectionId` at the time of execution. Meaning that each button had the `sectionId` of the last row. To fix it, I modified the event listener as such:

```
collapseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const clickedSectionId = collapseButton.dataset.sectionId; // Capture the specific sectionId
            const userRows = document.querySelectorAll(`.userRow[data-section-id="${clickedSectionId}"]`);
            userRows.forEach(row => {
                if (row.style.display === 'table-row') {
                    row.style.display = 'none';
                } else {
                    row.style.display = 'table-row';
                }
            });
```

I added a constant called `clickedSectionId` to capture the sectionId for each button and modified the `userRows` constant to use this new variable. This resulted in each button having the appropriate `sectionId` and thus expanding the expected sections.

---

I'm calling an API from my webpage and returning csv data in a table. The table shows a list of floating licenses that are in use and which users are using them. When the table loads on my webpage, the list of users will be hidden until the expand button is pressed. Each row of users has a sectionId that matches the product description it falls under. So the first button should only expand rows under the first product, etc.

[image: My Table]

The problem I'm experiencing is that when I inspect the table, the `sectionId` attribute is `undefined`.
[image: table_Inspect]

In my Javascript, I'm defining `sectionId` before the first forEach statement.

```
for (let i = 1; i < rows.length-1; i++){
    const dataRow = document.createElement('tr');
    const rowData = rows[i].split(',');

    let sectionId;
    rowData.forEach((data, columnIndex) => {
        const td = document.createElement('td');
        td.textContent = data;

        if(columnIndex === 0 && data.trim() !== ''){
            sectionId = data.trim();
            console.log("Section ID:", sectionId)
            const collapseButton = document.createElement('button');
            collapseButton.textContent = '+';
            collapseButton.dataset.sectionId = sectionId;
            //dataRow.classList.add('bundleRow');
            collapseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                const userRows = document.querySelectorAll(`.userRow[data-section-id="${sectionId}"]`);
                userRows.forEach(row => {
                    if(row.style.display === 'table-row'){
                        row.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                    else{
                        row.style.display = 'table-row';
                    }
                })
                //dataRow.classList.toggle('collapsed');
            });
            td.classList.add('first-column-cell');
            td.appendChild(collapseButton);
        }
        else if(columnIndex === 0 && data.trim() === ''){
            dataRow.classList.add('userRow')
            dataRow.dataset.sectionId = sectionId;
        }
        
        dataRow.appendChild(td);
    });

    // rowData.forEach(data => {
    //     const td = document.createElement('td');
    //     td.textContent = data;
    //     dataRow.appendChild(td);
    // });
    //dataRow.classList.add('collapsed');
    table.appendChild(dataRow);
}
```

My first thought was that sectionId needed to be declared somewhere else. So I moved it outside the for loop I'm using to create my table rows:

```
//Create Table Rows
    let sectionId;
    for (let i = 1; i < rows.length-1; i++){
        const dataRow = document.createElement('tr');
        const rowData = rows[i].split(',');

        rowData.forEach((data, columnIndex) => {
            const td = document.createElement('td');
            td.textContent = data;
```

Doing this fixes the undefined `sectionId` problem, but introduces another. When I go to expand the rows at this point, each button is expanding the rows for the last product only and not the rows for their respective product. Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Your `sectionId` variable is declared *outside* the outer `.forEach()`. Thus, there's only one variable shared by all the event handlers created in the iteration. The declaration should be *inside* the outer `.forEach()`.

Comment: Also, your code only assigns a value to `sectionId` in the first (true) part of that main `if` statement, but it *uses* the value in the `else` part. That also does not seem correct.

Comment: Moving `sectionId` inside the outer forEach() still results in an undefined `sectionId`. What's strange is I'm using a `console.log` statement to output the names of the sections, and they aren't undefined in the console. So I don't know why its even having that problem.

Comment: Yes. Note my second comment: `sectionId` is only assigned a value in the true part of the `if` statement. However, the false (`else`) code makes use of the variable. That seems very much unlikely to be correct; where is the value of `sectionId` supposed to come from in the `else` code?

Comment: Make sure you declare it local: `let sectionId = data.trim();`

Comment: Consider this: what happens when `columnIndex` is zero but `data.trim()` is the empty string? Then `sectionId` will never be set.

Comment: Are you saying I need to set `sectionId = data.trim()` in the else if statement?